# Run controller code once per page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I set a property in the base controller so that I can have access to its value from every action. Originally I put code to get the value (from a cookie) in the `OnActionExecuting` method, which works, but then I realized it's going to get called on every action call (some pages may run it hundreds of times because of repeating partial views).  How could I do it so it's only called once per page?

I looked at a similar answered question... [How to call a function *only once* in ASP.NET MVC page cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559553/how-to-call-a-function-only-once-in-asp-net-mvc-page-cycle) but the answer only deals with Ajax requests, which is not my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "once per page"? You do realize that a new controller instance is [generally] created each time a GET or POST request is made, don't you? You could use a `static` property, but that will be invoked once per app domain. To set it once per user session, consider using a session state variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @philsandler mentioned you can use the same solution. BUT I would still use an Action Filter to make it reusable and contained. Something like below.

```
public class RunOnlyPerAction : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            //read cookie
        }
    }
}


 [RunOnlyPerAction]
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

Comment: but it's not an ajax request, I have pages that contain partial views and they're displayed on the 'parent' view with a `@html.action(xxx)` for example.

Comment: I think my question didn't make much sense now that I'm reading it again. I'm thinking I could do what I want with an action filter so marking this as answer.

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078534/asp-net-mvc-lifecycle-once-per-page-request