# ASP.NET MVC Lifecycle - Do Some Work Once Per Page Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to perform some work per web request to a .NET MVC Web Application.  Specifically, I'd like to make a log entry into a DB for each page load.

Performing this work in an overridden Controller class `Controller.Initialize()` method doesn't work, because a [new controller is created with every call to @Html.Action()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425920/asp-net-mvc-controller-created-for-every-request).  Thus, if a child action is called from a view, then I end up double logging--which isn't what I want.

How can I insert some work into the MVC Lifecycle, such that it executes once per page request?

Comment: Try `BeginRequest` event in global.asax

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin `Try BeginRequest event in global.asax` **BeginRequest** event is also called multiple times in a single  page load.

Comment: Vsevolod, do you mean Application_BeginRequest?  I just tried it.  No, that method isn't called per web request.

Comment: Do keep in mind that there's no such thing as pages in MVC. You should reformulate your requirement in terms of controller actions. You'll then have to get clear on which controller actions you want to log and which you do not.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Yes the title might be, "Do Some Work Once Per _Web_ Request".

Comment: What do you consider to be a web request? It's really not a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in the `Initialize` if the action is a Child Action.

```
ControllerContext.IsChildAction
```

Comment: Attempting that `if (!ControllerContext.IsChildAction) { }` snippet in `protected override void Initialize()` doesn't work because ControllerContext is null.

Comment: Romias, I explored your suggestion again.  I noticed that `ControllerContext.IsChildAction` _is_ available in `protected override void OnActionExecuted()`.

Comment: Instead of doing it in Initialize... create a GlobalFilter, and register it in Global.asax

Comment: OnActionExecuted is triggered just before start rendering the view, and after you passed the Model to the View(model). So in that moment you can log info of the model itself (serialize it for example).

Comment: Thanks.  Using `ControllerContext.IsChildAction` in `protected override void OnActionExecuted()` is working for me.

Comment: Of course, it also fires for actions which are not rendering views.

Answer (score 4):

You can use either **OnActionExecuting** or **OnActionExecuted**.

For example,

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [LogActionFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class LogActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // If you register globally, you need this check.
        if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
        {
           Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // If you register globally, you need this check.
        if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
        {
           Log("OnActionExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    private void Log(string methodName, RouteData routeData)
    {
        var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = routeData.Values["action"];
        var message = String.Format("{0} controller:{1} action:{2}", methodName, controllerName, actionName);
        Debug.WriteLine(message, "Action Filter Log");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Win, that may work; I had considered creating a new ActionFilterAttribute.  But I believe I'd have to decorate (apply this new attribute) to numerous existing controller actions.  Is this right?

Comment: Yes. Ideally, you just add LogActionFilter to important Action methods only. In other words, you do not want to log each and every action methods, because logging is expensive.

Comment: @Michael, you don't have to apply the attribute to every controller, you can register it globally.

Comment: @Michael Craig is correct. If you register globally, make sure you check **IsChildAction**. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Win, Creating a new `ActionFilterAttribute` looks like a good solution as well. :) @Craig W. I didn't know that I could register it globally. Thanks for your help!